# Unable to reference objects in a referenced assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that has many projects in it.

The `SqlSmoke.Objects` project references the `SqlSmoke.Data` project.

I set a reference in `SqlSmoke.Objects` to the solution `SqlSmoke.Data`. I am then able to compile the entire solution.

However,`SqlSmoke.Data` does not appear in the intellisense as shown below. However, when I change my namespace to `SqlSmoke.Fred`, I do see `SqlSmoke.Data` in intellisense.

I don't *see* any circular references or other warnings in the Output window that suggest that something else is going on.

What might I look for to understand why I cannot reference objects in the Data project from the Objects project?

```
using SqlSmoke.Data;


namespace SqlSmoke.Objects
{   
    public class Class2
    {
        public void Junk()
        {
            SqlSmoke.Data.  //No intellisense
        }        
    }
}
```

If I change the Namespace, I get Intellisense:

```
using SqlSmoke.Data;


namespace SqlSmoke.ObjectsChangedNamespace
{   
    public class Class2
    {
        public void Junk()
        {
            SqlSmoke.Data.CodeObjectData.AddCodeObject("Test");  //Now I see intellisense
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this one time and just needed to restart Visual Studio. The changing the namespace to SqlSmoke.Fred seems weird to me; that didn't happen when I experienced this but I never tried changing the namespace before I restarted.

Comment: It may help to mention which version and edition of visual studio you use.

Comment: Restarting doesn't help. I still get Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'SqlSmoke.Objects.SqlSmoke' . Not sure why it lists SqlSmoke twice. Is this a clue?

Comment: Do you have a namespace 'SqlSmoke.Objects.SqlSmoke'?

Comment: No, I do not. That error is puzzling but it's probably a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [sub]namespace/class name collision. Use:

```
public void Junk()
{
  global::SqlSmoke.Data. 
}
```

and it will work.

Comment: You are correct. Though I am not sure as to the source of the collision. Does "Global::" essentially say "look to an external reference" or how do I read this?

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx - they have an example